# How can I disable month selection in the jQuery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying disable the left/right buttons that allow the user to change months. I've removed the drop down list of months but can't get rid of the buttons.

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    duration: 'fast'
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can effectively disable them using `stepMonths` by making them go nowhere when clicked, like this:

```
$("#date").datepicker({
  changeMonth: false,
  changeYear: false,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  duration: 'fast',
  stepMonths: 0
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/LttVe/)

Or, you could remove the buttons like this:

```
$("#date").datepicker({
  changeMonth: false,
  changeYear: false,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  duration: 'fast'
}).focus(function() {
  $(".ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next").remove();
});​
```

[You can give that a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/LttVe/1/), this works because the default `showOn` option is `focus`, if you're using a different event, just bind to that *after* the `.datepicker()` call (so its event runs first, you can't hide what isn't created yet).

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned solution did not work for me, I developped this:

```
$('#datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-next').remove();
$('#datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-prev').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it directly in jQuery (or if it's possible).

But if you can't find a way to do it in there, you could always just hide the buttons in css.

The css selectors you want are (from memory so you might need to check)

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev, 
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next
{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my way to make datepicker pick only year:

```
if (document.styleSheets[0].addRule) {
   document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".ui-datepicker-calendar", "display: none;");
else {
   document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(".ui-datepicker-calendar {display: none;}", 0);
}

 .datepicker({    
                  dateFormat: 'yy',
                  showMonthAfterYear: false,
                  changeMonth: false,
                  changeYear: true,
                  showButtonPanel: true,
                  stepMonths: 12,
                  monthNames: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
                  onChangeMonthYear: function (year) {
                      $(this).val(year);
                  }
             });
```