# Disable Next in Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, disabled-control

Is there any other way by which I cannot allow the user to select next months.
I had gone through some threads but I don't want to disable both next and previous buttons by using step functionality as directed in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501808/jquery-datepicker-disable-month-selection).

```
 function bindPicker() {
        $("input[type=text][id*=Date]").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-100:+0",
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: "../../images/Calender.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: "M-yy"
        });
    }
```

Comment: There is not any native jQuery UI method to disable this feature.
What is wrong with the other thread ?

Comment: why don't you just set `maxdate`

Comment: Mohammad: yes that was a way and I am able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the maxDate option to 0, this set the max date to +0 days from today.

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({maxDate: '0'});
```

More info: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Answer (score 6):

Well if you are looking to simply remove the next/previous options and only use a forced month in your code, you can use CSS.

```
.ui-datepicker-next,.ui-datepicker-prev{display:none;}
```

This will just remove the next/prev buttons all together.  Then if need be you can even put in like some .toggle() code to show/hide them when needed.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wish I could select more than one answer.

Comment: this answer better than the previous if you set the max date or min date jquery disable the buttons but i this way the buttons working good !

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to hide the next/previous when they're disabled (ie. all valid dates are within a single month), use the following:

```
.ui-datepicker-prev.ui-state-disabled { display: none; }
.ui-datepicker-next.ui-state-disabled { display: none; }
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank You :)

Answer (score -1):

Datepicker with hiding next and prev buttons and date format and defined date.

```
$("#dateTextId")
    .datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-M-y",stepMonths:0})
    .datepicker('setDate',new Date(date_string));
```