# How to hide jquery datepicker prev/next text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

[Here is code](http://jsfiddle.net/kkadso/0u1o7rzz/2/)

[image]

You can see the button and the `prev` ,`next` overlap

How to hide the  `prev` ,`next` text ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Next in Jquery datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040204/disable-next-in-jquery-datepicker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0u1o7rzz/4/)

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next span {
    color: transparent;
}
```

You can use css to hide the next and previous button as shown in the demo

Answer (score 2):

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next span {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

You can hide the font by setting the css `font-size` to `0`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0u1o7rzz/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to Hide/Show the prev/next navigation.

```
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker().focus(function () {
        $(".ui-datepicker-next").show();
        $(".ui-datepicker-prev").show();
    });
});
```

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/Diggetydog/pen/YzyxKNO)

Comment: Thanks! this answer helped me, in my case I changed the code to: $(". ui-datepicker-next").removeAttr("title"); $(". ui-datepicker-prev").removeAttr("title");

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way is by setting the text to empty string. In your code, the date picker is initialized in Javascript/JQuery, and you can modify the initialization as follows:

```js
$('.week-picker').datepicker({
   /* ... your existing intialization code ... */
   nextText: '',
   prevText: '',
   /* ... */
});
```

Alternatively, and in cases where you can't access the initialization in code, you can change the text after initialization:

```js
$('.week-picker').datepicker('option', 'nextText', '');
$('.week-picker').datepicker('option', 'prevText', '');
```

I like this method better than setting the color to `transparent`, as suggested in one answer, as transparent strings are still selectable by the user. I also like it better than hiding the entire `.ui-datepicker-next/prev` elements as suggested by another answer, because that will hide the image as well, not only the text.